# Django-REST API Raising an Error in Serializer when Email Exisit

Tags: python, django, post, get

so a quick over view, the Front ends sends me a email,password and confirmpassword.

and i store them in an API and then will later on store in the database, but for the mean time, i am only saving them when the sent email doesn't exist

first of all that's my **views.py**

```
class UserList(APIView):

def get(self,request):
    users = Users.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(users,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self,request):

    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    #here i serialize the data entered by the user
    if serializer.is_valid():
        try:
          #and then i check if the email already exists or not, if it not exist, it will save it in the API, if not it should raise an errro!, i tried saying serializers.validationerror bs that wouldn't work at all.

            match = Users.objects.get(email=serializer.validated_data["email"])
        except Users.DoesNotExist:
            # Unable to find a user, this is fine]
            serializer.save()
            print ('money here come the money')
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        raise (?!)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace and fix indentation. Also, what is this `raise(?!)` supposed to mean on third last line ?

Comment: >  raise serializers.ValidationError("Email Exists!")

Comment: That was the raise in the first place, but that doesn't work.

Comment: This is a view method, why would you want to raise an exception. You're supposed to return a Response object.

Comment: yes i know i am supposed to return a responce, so i wanted at first to return a JSON saying error or something, but with the case being i am using try and catch i have to end with raise.

Comment: that's why i am asking , because i am stuck.

Comment: No, you dont have to end with raise. try and except are doing its separate thing checking if the object exist or not. You just need to return a Response object with whatever error message you want.

Comment: Thank you so much:)
i deleted the raise and just added an
            else:
                return Response("The Email Already Exists!", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a `Response` object rather than raise an Exception.

**Solution**:

```
return Response({
  'success': False,
  'detail': 'Email already exists'
}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Replace `raise(?!)` with the above piece of code.